# Unable to integrate crashlytics in eclipse with ADT

Tags: android, eclipse-adt, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, crashlytics-beta

I followed setting up plugin to integrate `crashlytics` from this link 
https://www.crashlytics.com/onboard

From eclipse, I logged into my fabric account and selected my project.

Plugin made necessary changes to manifest and launch activity.

It asked to build & run my app to complete step 1.

But I am getting -

> ../kit-libs/com-crashlytics-sdk-android_crashlytics/bin(missing) 
>   ../kit-libs/com-crashlytics-sdk-android_crashlytics-core/bin(missing) 
>   ../kit-libs/com-crashlytics-sdk-android_beta/bin(missing) 
>   ../kit-libs/com-crashlytics-sdk-android_answers/bin(missing) 
>   ../kit-libs/io-fabric-sdk-android_fabric/bin(missing)

Please guide me how to build `crashlytics` and integrate further.

Comment: The only solution was to migrate my project to android studio and integrate crashlytics from studio.

Answer (score 1):

In your project, there are 5 fabric libraries under the "kit-libs" folder.

Right click the build.xml in every library -> Run As -> Ant Build

It should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Although @Pyngon is on the right track, I found that the my Ant build run configuration within Eclipse (Mars) didn't know, or pick up, the 'ANDROID_HOME' environmental variable (`echo $ANDROID_HOME` confirms the SDK's path as '/Users/my.name/Library/Android/sdk' on my Mac, Yosemite 10.10.4).

To get Ant to use this variable, I had to define it within each individual run configuration, e.g.:

- /your.project.path/platforms/android/kit-libs/io-fabric-sdk-android_fabric/build.xml -> Run As -> External Tools Configurations -> Environment (tab) -> Add new 'ANDROID_HOME' SDK path value.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, I was able to resolve this issue with Eclipse. This is what I did.
Configure the build path for the io-fabric-sdk-android_fabric project that is imported by the Fabric eclipse plugin.

Select a valid android build target, in my case I selected Android 4.4.2. Click 'OK' to apply.

You might need to repeat this for all the Fabric projects imported. i.e crashylitics, digits, twitter, mopub e.t.c.

com-crashlytics-sdk-android_answers
com-crashlytics-sdk-android_beta
com-crashlytics-sdk-android_crashlytics
com-crashlytics-sdk-android_crashlytics-core
com-digits-sdk-android_digits
com-twitter-sdk-android_tweet-composer
com-twitter-sdk-android_tweet-ui
com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter
com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core