# Error after adding Fabric Crashlytics in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, crashlytics

I am implementing crashlytics in my Android app. I installed fabric plugin for Eclipse using install new software. I created a sample software for checking the implementation of flurry and it worked successfully,but when i tried adding flurry to my app software it started giving me error:

```
R cannot be resolved to a variable
```

if I  remove all the additions done by fabric to my source code and build the project everything goes fine

I tried by updating the Android SDK,ADT but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Can't help right now, but I'm in the exact same boat - I'll let you know if I solve it (apologies).

Answer (score 0):

I had several issues integrating Crashlytics. [Here, I discuss a resolution for building missing/not-built Crashlytics 'kits' libraries in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568740/unable-to-integrate-crashlytics-in-eclipse-with-adt/32436127#32436127).

My second and final issue concerned the merging of 'AndroidManifest.xml' files, between my main project and it's dependency projects. For instance, the `min:sdk`.... The following links demonstrate the fix **(N.B. I will edit this further, later)**:

[Gradle: How to merge Android manifest files for different buildTypes which need the same Activity, but with different intent-filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708076/gradle-how-to-merge-android-manifest-files-for-different-buildtypes-which-need/22007198#22007198)

[Gradle merge wrapper/sub-module's Android manifest into a main module's manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239844/gradle-merge-wrapper-sub-modules-android-manifest-into-a-main-modules-manifest/22007699#22007699)

http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2014/04/10/android-gradle-manifest-merge

Answer (score 0):

A little too late, but it sure will help

Go to your project/project.properties, remove the text `manifestmerger.enabled=true`

Then the **R cannot be resolved** error should be fixed now.

Next if you try to run the project, it will (hopefully not) pop up an error something like this in your **Console**

`Android Dx Error1
Failed to convert to Dalvik format`

Here you will need to add in **ALL** the library from *kit-libs* folder into your build path, **BUT**, DO NOT check all the Craslytics's libraries in **Order & Export**, including the **android.jar**

Build & Run, the project should work now (In my case)

Hopefully you can too.